# Accessing struct object array in no of rows in section returning null

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

I am trying to download data and put it in struct objects and trying to load data in table view  .I am downloading it in to array and append it to struct object.when I am taking return array.count  in no of rows in section its working when I use  return objectArray[section].funcName.count  its not working values are getting late to download also

```
    import UIKit
import Alamofire

class GalleryVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var galleryTable: UITableView!
    var imageUrlArray:[String] = [String]()
    var imageCount:[String] = [String]()
    var funName1:[String] = [String]()
    var gaimage1:String = ""
    var gacount1:String = ""
    var funname1:String = ""
    struct Objects {
        var imageName : [String]!
        var imageCount : [String]!
        var funcName:[String]!
        }
    var objectArray = [Objects]()
    var objectArrayFilter = [Objects]()
    var inSearchMode = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadGalleryList()
        galleryTable.delegate = self
        galleryTable.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
            print(objectArray[section].funcName.count)
            return objectArray[section].funcName.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"gallerycell", for: indexPath) as? GalleryListCell{

            if inSearchMode{

                cell.galleryImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: objectArrayFilter[indexPath.section].imageName[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1862205"))
                cell.galleryphotono.text = objectArrayFilter[indexPath.section].imageCount[indexPath.row]+" photos"
                cell.galleryFunction.text = objectArrayFilter[indexPath.section].funcName[indexPath.row]

                return cell

            }

            cell.galleryImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: objectArray[indexPath.section].imageName[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1862205"))
            cell.galleryphotono.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].imageCount[indexPath.row]+" photos"
            cell.galleryFunction.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].funcName[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }
        else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }


    func downloadGalleryList(){

        let bmiChapterUrl = URL(string:Gallery_List)!
        Alamofire.request(bmiChapterUrl).responseJSON{ response in
            let result = response.result
            print(response)
            print(result)


            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

                if let bmi = dict["result"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
                {


                    for obj in bmi {

                        if let gaimage = obj["image"] as? String
                        {
                            print(gaimage)
                            self.gaimage1 = gaimage

                            self.imageUrlArray.append(gaimage)

                        }
                        if let gacount = obj["count"] as? String
                        {
                            self.gacount1 = gacount
                            print(gacount)

                            self.imageCount.append(gacount)

                        }

                        if let funname = obj["event"] as? String
                        {
                            print(funname)
                            self.funname1 = funname
                            self.funName1.append(funname)
                        }


                    }

                }
            }

            print(self.imageUrlArray,self.imageCount,self.funName1
            )
            self.objectArray.append(Objects(imageName: self.imageUrlArray, imageCount:self.imageCount,funcName: self.funName1))
            print(self.objectArray)

            self.galleryTable.reloadData()

        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false

            view.endEditing(true)

            galleryTable.reloadData()

        } else {

            inSearchMode = true


            objectArrayFilter = objectArray.filter { $0.imageName.contains(where: { $0.contains(searchBar.text!) }) }

            print(objectArrayFilter)

            galleryTable.reloadData()


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clear your code for more understand

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo just tell me what all things u required

Comment: If your table view contains only one section why do you use an enclosing array? And it seems that you are using multiple arrays as data source. Don't do that. That's a misuse of object oriented programming.

Comment: @vadian I just edited my code have a look

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo I edited my code

Comment: @vadian the link points to something else

Comment: Your design is wrong. Your `Object` (singular) struct is supposed to contain one item respectively  and `numberOfRowsInSection ` is supposed to return `objectArray.count`. Instead of **one** `Objects` object containing **multiple** arrays you have to use **multiple** `Object` objects containing **single** objects

Comment: @vadian I am new to iOS programming can u point out a tutorial for learning and fixing that

Comment: There are millions of tutorials. You can use any tutorial which provides one section and a struct / class as model.

Comment: @vadian done it bro. thanks a lot!